# django models choices list - decending order output

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.7

I asked this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227302/django-models-choices-list) yesterday.

The code I now have to display the choices list in my models.py is:

```
YOB_TYPES = Choices(*(
    ((0, 'select_yob', _(' Select Year of Birth')),
     (2000, 'to_present', _('2000 to Present'))) +
    tuple((i, str(i)) for i in xrange(1990, 2000)) +
    ((1, 'unspecified', _('Prefer not to answer')),))
)
....
year_of_birth_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=YOB_TYPES, default=YOB_TYPES.select_yob, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
....
```

The choices list is now displayed with the year of birth running from 1990 to 1999 (ascending order) as shown below:

[image]

**How do I change the code so that the year of birth dates are displayed 1999 to 1990 (decending order) as shown below:**

[image]

I have searched but cannot locate anything related to my issue - reversing ( .reverse() ) the tuple output - maybe I am searching the wrong topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this line:

```
tuple((i, str(i)) for i in xrange(1990, 2000)) +
```

Adjust like so:

```
tuple((i, str(i)) for i in xrange(1999, 1989, -1) +
```

The third argument specifies your "step", in this case -1 (to go in reverse). Remember that with xrange, the second parameter is not included in the iteration, so use 1989 rather than 1990 (the same reason why you used 2000 earlier, rather than 1999).

Comment: Joseph, thanks for your answer. This really helped me. I thought that it would be a relatively simple solution - i just could not figure it out myself.